# testing multiple sessions with integration tests?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, integration-testing, cdi, jboss-arquillian

Is it possible to simulate multiple "sessions" in a java-ee container with a unit testing framework, such as Arquillian? I have `many sessions that interact with each other`, and I would like to simulate this happening with tests, in the production container itself. There is also JPA2 database behavior that I would like to test at the same time.

But I also want to make sure that CDI and session-scoped beans are doing what they're supposed to be doing. I don't want to run the server and a couple hours later find out that what I *thought* was a session-scoped bean is, for whatever reason, being instantiated more than once for that same session.

Many thanks for the help!

**EDIT**: I found this page about [testing contexts using Arquillian and Seam](http://ctpjava.blogspot.com/2010/08/test-drive-with-arquillian-and-cdi-part.html), but I'm having trouble understanding it. Could this approach be used for the above situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way currently, but that would be a great feature request!